# How can I auto select value of dropdown using an ID value?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I am creating a vehicle lookup service for visitors to my employer's website. By entering their vehicle details either manually or by entering their reg, the site products will be filtered to match fitment for that specific vehicle.

If the customer enters their reg and clicks submit, the results are captured in a hidden table on the same page. I want the manual selector values to update according to such hidden values.

How would I get the search data to show in the appropriate selector option? (I understand that none of the results is an option but if it was then how would I do it)

```html
Here is the manual vehicle details code:

<div class="block-content">
  <div class="level">
    <select class="ymm-select" name="_make">
      <option value="">-- Make --</option>
      <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="level">
    <select class="ymm-select disabled" name="_model" disabled="disabled">
      <option value="">-- Model --</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="level">
    <select class="ymm-select disabled" name="_year" disabled="disabled">
      <option value="">-- Year --</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="ymm-clear">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="ymm-extra" style="display:none">
    <div class="ymm-category-container">
      <div class="ymm-clear">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" title="Search" class="button ymm-submit-any-selection">Search</button>
</div>

Here is the vehicle result data:

<table class="table" hidden="">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Make:</td>
      <td id="dvla-search-make">FORD </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Model:</td>
      <td id="dvla-search-model">FOCUS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Year:</td>
      <td id="dvla-search-year">2009</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Engine:</td>
      <td id="dvla-search-engine">1753cc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="dvla-search-fuel">Fuel Type:</td>
      <td>DIESEL</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Use Javascript and AJAX request

Comment: What function would I use? I don't mind learning and looking this up for myself but my knowledge is very weak and I don't know where to start.

Comment: Using builtin `fetch` API would be a good start. Or if you're into jQuery you can use `$.ajax`, `$.get` or `$.post`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```js
window.addEventListener("load",() => { // when the page loads
  document.querySelectorAll("[id^=dvla-search]").forEach(entry => { // find all table cells with ids starting with dvla-search
    const val  = entry.innerText.trim();
    const name = entry.id.replace("dvla-search-","_");     // find the name of the 
    const elem = document.querySelector("[name="+name+"]") // select associated with the cell id
    if (elem) { // if found    
      let vals = [...elem.querySelectorAll("option")].map(opt => opt.value)
      if (!vals.includes(val)) { // only add if not already there
        const opt = new Option(val,val,true,true); // make an option and select it
        elem.appendChild(opt); // add the option
        elem.removeAttribute("disabled"); // allow selection
      }  
      else elem.value=val; // IF already there, select it
    }  
  })
});
```

```html
Here is the manual vehicle details code:

<div class="block-content">
  <div class="level">
    <select class="ymm-select" name="_make">
      <option value="">-- Make --</option>
      <option value="FORD">FORD</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="level">
    <select class="ymm-select disabled" name="_model" disabled="disabled">
      <option value="">-- Model --</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="level">
    <select class="ymm-select disabled" name="_year" disabled="disabled">
      <option value="">-- Year --</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="ymm-clear">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="ymm-extra" style="display:none">
    <div class="ymm-category-container">
      <div class="ymm-clear">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" title="Search" class="button ymm-submit-any-selection">Search</button>
</div>

Here is the vehicle result data:

<table class="table" hidden="">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Make:</td>
      <td id="dvla-search-make">FORD </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Model:</td>
      <td id="dvla-search-model">FOCUS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Year:</td>
      <td id="dvla-search-year">2009</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Engine:</td>
      <td id="dvla-search-engine">1753cc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="dvla-search-fuel">Fuel Type:</td>
      <td>DIESEL</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm unsure, I'll give that a go and see what happens. I'll also look up that code as I don't understand it.

Comment: I commented the script

Comment: Thank you for that. After testing the code, it creates an option but doesn't automatically select the created option when the page reloads. Is this possible?

Comment: Sorry to be a pain. Is it also possible to only select it from the list if it's an available option?

Comment: rather than create a new option

Comment: As if the option is already there (Ford in this case) it creates a duplicate option

Comment: Could I utilise the following code? .getElementsByTagName('option')[val].selected = 'selected'

Comment: `const opt = new Option(val,val,true,true);` see update. I do not know how you load the table so I did not handle duplicates.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. That appears to still be creating a duplicate. Would the value be case sensitive? As the option already there is Ford, whereas the table data states FORD

Comment: Ok, Now code will test if option is already there and select it if yes or create and select it i not